# "mightn't have" and "might not have"

Tags: american-english, british-english, contractions

In American English, are "mightn't have" and "might not have" both often used in speaking and writing?

How about "couldn't have" and "could not have"?

How about in British English? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure I've heard it sometimes. We even have [mightn't've](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mightn%27t%27ve). :-)

Comment: I'd say "mightn't have" is the one I hear or see least regularly (in the US), but any of these would be understood.

Comment: @DamkerngT.:  Which dialect of English or region do you refer to?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure because I listen to both accents (AmE and BrE) a lot. Earlier I was more used to AmE, but I found myself listen to BBC Radio more and more lately. Maybe I've heard it in both accents.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Pronounced /maɪʔənʌv/ where I come from.

Comment: I live in England and have never heard/seen anyone use "mightn't" (Or perhaps don't recall anyone doing so)

Comment: @Amber: [Mightn't](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn't%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) you have at least come across it in a *book?* It's not all that unusual, surely?

Answer (score 6):

My gut feel is that the *mightn't* contraction is ***more common in BrE than AmE*** (but I've no reason to think most Americans find it at all "unusual").

I'm not *sure* if this is a valid way of using Google Books estimated results, but note these figures...

> 1: [color](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22color%22&tbm=bks):159M, [colour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22colour%22&tbm=bks):53M
>    2: [might + color](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22might%22%20%22color%22&tbm=bks):12M, [might + colour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22might%22%20%22colour%22&tbm=bks):6M
>    3: [mightn't + color](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22mightn%27t%22%20%22color%22&tbm=bks):4310, [mightn't + colour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22mightn%27t%22%20%22colour%22&tbm=bks):5680

According to #1, there are three times as many instances of US *color* as there are UK *colour*. Since there's no reason to suppose Americans use the word any more often than Brits, I assume the relevant US corpus is about three times bigger than the US one.

All things being equal, we could expect the #2 AmE count to be about 18M, not 12M. But note that overall prevalance of *might* has [fallen by a third](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=might&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,might;,c0) in the last couple of centuries. Older texts in the Google Books corpus are more likely to be BrE, so the AmE aversion to *might* is weaker than the bare figures suggest.

But after allowing for the implication of the above (Americans are perhaps 20-30% less likely than Brits to use the word *might* in any given utterance), we should still expect the #3 AmE count to be **11K**, not 4K.

Regardless of whether the *absolute* values of those Google Books estimates are accurate, I see no reason to suppose that the *ratios* aren't meaningful. So I think this validates my gut feel.

---

The figures for [couldn't + color](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22couldn%27t%22%20%22color%22&tbm=bks):2.8M and [couldn't + colour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mightn%27t%20cost%20a%20penny%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22couldn%27t%22%20%22colour%22&tbm=bks):0.85M suggest that the US aversion to *mightn't* doesn't extend to *couldn't*.

Comment: I'm in the U.S., and I'd concur with your last statement. I would have no qualms about writing _couldn't_ in a letter (_sorry I couldn't be at your wedding_), but I think that – until today – I've never written the word _mightn't_ (_sorry, I mightn't be able to attend your anniversary party_). That said, I'd have no problem understanding it, of course.

Comment: I'm from the U.S. and would say that "mightn't" is rather uncommon. Although I do note that Firefox's US English spellcheck does recognize it. Then again, I've seen it written much more often than spoken.

Answer (score 0):

In American English mightn’t is extremely uncommon, but still understood.